# Pass NSIndexPath by reference

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC and want to create a method that passes in an indexPath by reference so I can change its value:

```
-(void)configureIndexPaths:(__bridge NSIndexPath**)indexPath anotherIndexPath:(__bridge NSIndexPath**)anotherIndexPath
{
      indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:*indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0];
      anotherIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:*anotherIndexPath.row + 1 inSection:0];
}
```

But this gives me a property row not found error. How can I address this.

And another conceptual question: if my my goal is just to change the value of indexPath that was passed in to the method, couldn't passing by pointer also do that? Why would I choose to pass by reference rather than pass by pointer?

Comment: Why not just have the method return a new nsindexpath?

Comment: I'm passing in two unique indexPaths that I want to change

Comment: newIndexPath is a separate index path

Comment: I always thought double pointers were __autoreleasing, not __bridge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do this:

```
-(void) configureIndexPaths:(NSIndexPath*__autoreleasing *)indexPath anotherIndexPath:(__bridge NSIndexPath*__autoreleasing *)anotherIndexPath
{
    if (indexPath)
        *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[(*indexPath) row] + 1 inSection:0];
    if (anotherIndexPath)
        *anotherIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[(*indexPath) row] + 1 inSection:0];
}
```

You should use `__autoreleasing`, so that the objects are properly autoreleased when they are created, as well as checking for a `NULL` pointer being passed in. If you want a true `pass-by-reference`, look into objc++ and a `NSIndexPath *&`.

Answer (score 2):

> if my my goal is just to change the value of `indexPath` that was passed in to the method, couldn't passing by pointer also do that?

Not really, because the index path isn't mutable. You'd have to construct a new index path object and return that.

> Why would I choose to pass by reference rather than pass by pointer?

The only real reason to do this in ObjC is to have multiple return values. The most frequent use of this technique is to have a method that returns an object or success/failure indicator and that can also set up an error object if necessary.

In this case, you have two objects you want to get back out of the method; one way to do that is with the pass-by-reference trick. It may make your life simpler to pass in the two index paths as you are now, but return an `NSArray` with the new ones:

```
 - (NSArray *)configureIndexPaths:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath anotherIndexPath:( NSIndexPath*)anotherIndexPath
{
    NSIndexPath * newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row]+1 inSection:0];
    NSIndexPath * anotherNewPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[anotherIndexPath row]+1 inSection:0];
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newPath, anotherNewPath, nil];
}
```

Comment: So if I pass by pointer and I do indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWith...], then this doesn't change the value of the original index path that was called with the method?

Comment: If it looks like `(NSIndexPath **)arg{ *arg = [NSIndexPath indexPath...`, that will change the passed-in pointer, from the caller's point of view.